# Hechshered, pareve sausage casing

Tags: product-recommendation, cooking-bishul

I've become interested in sausage-making. However, I have had some understandable difficulty finding non-meat casings. Furthermore, I have been unable to find pareve casings with a hashgacha. Is anyone aware of someplace from whence I could order pareve sausage-casing?

Comment: Are you looking only for edible casings, or would plastic based casings be acceptable?

Comment: Curious. Why do they need to be parve? If the sausage is meat, once the sausage is cooked, the casing becomes meat, anyway.

Comment: @DanF, they presumably have a longer shelf-life than fleischig casings.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I haven't the faintest. It makes the most sense to get edible casings, as I don't need to worry about removing them before eating.

Comment: So apparently your interest in your Germanic roots is not limited to religion:) Bratwurst anyone? +1 cause I have searched for this stuff to no avail.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is this on topic?

Comment: @DanF, if you can find fleischig casings w/ a reliable hechsher and a long shelf-life (preferably outside of the freezer) I'd consider that a good answer, despite the fact that it's not in the OP.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt  When I lived in Wash. Heights as a lad (I was that, once) there was a kosher butcher that made its own "yekke" sausages, aufschnit, rauchfleish, and about 20 types of liverwurst & bratwurst in their own factory behind the store. They closed about 10 years ago. Perhaps there's a "remnant" of that store, Bloch & Falk, somewhere. I'll research, B"N. You might want to try contacting a "common" kosher sausage producer such as Ables & Heyman or "999". One of my wife's friends used to own 999.  See https://germanjewishcuisine.com/2013/09/24/bloch-falk-a-special-wurst-sausage-store/

Comment: In the 3rd post of the link I included in the previous comment, the writer says that http://www.gref-voelsings.de/ used to and still makes casings for the Jewish consumer. I'm assuming that you read German??? If so, you might find something on that web site or, perhaps can contact them. If they do make kosher casings, inform us!

Comment: @DanF, it appears that Gref-Völsings doesn't actually make kosher products. Rindwurst was created for folks outside of the IRG or the main Orthodox community.

Answer (score 1):

I viewed the most recent [OK Passover guide](http://docplayer.net/48148679-Ok-passover-products-food-guide.html) (2017). They list kosher casings made by Kalle GmbH.

Here is some technical info about one of their products, [Naloform](http://www.brgpack.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/NaloForm_englisch.pdf). It seems that these casings are made from a polymer / fiber. From [this page](http://kalle.de/en/business-areas/fibrous-casings/):

> Nalo casings are made from cellulose obtained from wood. This material
>   is processed through a number of steps to create viscose. The
>   breakthrough Kalle achieved in 1929 was to pass the liquid viscose
>   through a ring nozzle and thus create a seamless tube. The product
>   name, Nalo, is a contraction of the German word “nahtlos”, meaning
>   seamless. Nalo casings are usually strengthened through the addition
>   of a special fiber paper that is similar to that used in tea bags and
>   coffee pods. The finished product is called a “fibrous casing”.
>
> Both the viscose and paper are made from renewable, natural materials.
>   Kalle fibrous casings are thus a popular choice among eco-aware
>   customers and consumers.

It seems that you should be able to make your sausages using this product. If you do, let me know. I'll buy some only if you name your company "Noach's Frankfurters!"

Answer (score 0):

Victorian Hide and Skin Producers in Australia used to process hides from local shechitah for sausage skin manufacturing but that stopped about 10 years ago when they were bought out by a Japanese firm.

Lichorah parev and collagen are not contradictory since hides are inedible.

Comment: My family will not use mammal-derived products with pareve or milchigs (other than milk of course). I don't know if this hakpadah is unique to us, but as such, we regard cow gelatin and collagen as fleischig and as such, it requires a hashgachah regardless (even though there are those opinions which say it doesn't)

Comment: Animal products would also spoil more quickly